# How to use GitKraken on Heroku

Tags: git, version-control, heroku

I'm new to using Heroku and I noticed that the way we push our code to it is by using git commands.

I was wondering if it's possible to use GitKraken to do it.

I used GitKraken only on 2 BitBucket projects, but I don't know how to configure and start a project that is not GutHub, BitBucket, or the options that GitKraken has.

Is it possible?

PS: I believe one method could be attaching a GitHub account to Heroku, but I would like to avoid that for now.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it’s just a Git repository you can use any Git GUI without additional configuration...?

Comment: I will take a look again into GitKraken. I guess I'm missing something, as their options are "Local only" and then GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket and Azure.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so the way was not to "Init Repo" but use the "Clone Repo"

That did the trick.

Only thing I needed was to get a token as a password using heroku authorizations:create to get a long lasting token. Then used that as password and my email as username when GitKraken asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67453276/161471

To use Heroku git (something like https://gitTo use Heroku git (something like https://git.heroku.com/reponame.git) with GitKraken, please use **email as username**, and use **authorization token as password**.

I create a long-term password to use with GitKraken by

1. Go to Heroku UI then login
2. Account Settings
3. Applications
4. Authorization / Create
   authorization *(don't set expire if you want long-term access)*